# Intuition behind tangent vectors as maps from $C^\infty$ functions to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: differential-geometry

In Wald's *General Relativity*, he writes:

> Thus on a manifold $M$ let $\mathscr{F}$ denote the collection of $C^\infty$ functions from $M$ into $\mathbb{R}$. We define a tangent vector $v$ at point $p \in M$ to be a map $v : \mathscr{F} \to \mathbb{R}$ which (1) is linear and (2) obeys the Leibnitz rule.

Unfortunately I have very minimal background in the language of differential geometry and don't find this very intuitive; a clearer explanation would be really helpful.

Comment: A tangent direction should be something that you can differentiate a (smooth) function along.  (Think about directional derivatives in multi-variable calculus.)  Taking this derivative gives a linear functional satisfying the Leibnitz rule.

Comment: @tracing: So is it correct to think of the "derivation" (the map which Wald calls the 'tangent vector' and what the Wikipedia article about tangent spaces calls a 'derivation') as being the directional derivative in the direction of a particular tangent vector (in the sense of being the velocity of some curve)?

Comment: @ElizabethLin: Yes, that's exactly the idea.  On a general manifold, it is harder to define a tangent vector geometrically, so one approach is just to define it in terms of derivations.  (To show this is justified, you have to show that for an open set in $\mathbb R^n$, every derivation really comes from some directional derivative.)  One can also develop the theory more geometrically, by first thinking about curves, then differentiating along a curve, and then finally showing that all derivations arise in this way; but sometimes it is more convenient (or just faster) to take derivations ...

Comment: ... to be the definition.

Comment: @Dan: I'm not sure why you say this.  There is an isomorphism (of vector spaces) between tangent vectors (defined any other way) and tangent vectors defined as the space of derivations at a point.   So it is reasonable to call such a thing a tangent vector.  Perhaps you could instead call it the derivation associated to the tangent vector, but this is more words for exactly the same amount of information.  But I wouldn't use the word "representative" in this context, just because it makes it sound as if some sort of equivalence relation is being imposed.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the Wikipedia article [Tangent space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space). The maps which define your tangent vectors are called derivations. So look in the cited article for the definition of tangent space in terms of derivations. But I suggest you to read the whole article. If you want to get deeper insights, also compare Bröcker, Jänich "Introduction to differential topology", where 3 different definitions of the tangent space are mentioned and proved to be equivalent. Have fun!

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the suggestions and will take a look at the book you mentioned.